# How to get uWSGI Python exception message pretty printing?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, uwsgi, pretty-print

Would like to know if there is a simple, easy way to have uWSGI pretty print exception messages (for Python specifically, not sure if the settings are particular to Python or not).

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean getting the exception message in the browser, just add --catch-exceptions

IMPORTANT: it could expose sensitive informations, do not use in production !!!